# How many bytes can be sent in first TCP window?

Tags: networking, tcp

I read somewhere (but cannot find the source anymore) that there is a certain maximum number of bytes that can be sent in the first TCP window. Sending more data requires ACK from the receiver, hence another round-trip. To reduce website latency, all above-the-fold content, including HTTP reply headers, should be less than this number of bytes.

Can anybody remember what the maximum number of bytes in the first TCP window is and how it is calculated?

Comment: It is regulated by `initcwd` (initial tcp congestion window). [Here's](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/tcp_initcwnd_paper.pdf) paper witch argues increasing that param.

Comment: Also, [here's practical reference](http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/tune-tcp-initcwnd-for-optimum-performance/) for tuning this param.

Comment: @SlavaBacherikov Please post this as a self-contained answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is regulated by initial tcp congestion window (`initcwnd`). This parameter determines how many segments (MSS) could be sent without waiting for ACK at first phase of slow start. Currently recommended value for most workloads is [10](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/tcp_initcwnd_paper.pdf), but some old systems still using 4. Also note, used window size depends on clients receive window too, so if some client will advertise receive window lower than your initial congestion window, it will be used this receive window as limit.

For more info, refer to this [page](https://hpbn.co/building-blocks-of-tcp/#slow-start).

Comment: Found the answer within the link you sent. MSS is 1430 bytes for IP over Ethernet and `initcwnd` is 10 for most workloads, hence, 14300 bytes can be sent in the first TCP window.